# Error while accessing multi-dimensional associative array in PHP (AWS/ResulData)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, multidimensional-array, amazon-rekognition

I've been trying to implement Celebrity Recognition via AWS Rekognition using PHP. I was able to get the ResultData using,

```
$result = $client->recognizeCelebrities();
```

And I converted the $result to an array using,

```
$postResult = (array) $result;
```

I tried to print the array $postResult using,

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($postResult);
echo '</pre>';
```

and it printed something similar to,

```
Array
(
 [Aws\Resultdata] => Array
 (
   [CelebrityFaces] => Array
   (
     [0] => Array
     (
      [Name] => Emily Blunt                            
     )
   )
  )
)
```

I wanted to print only the value 'Name'. So I used,

```
echo $postResult['Aws\Resultdata']['CelebrityFaces'][0]['Name'];
```

But it throws an error as, **Undefined index: Aws\Resultdata**

I also tried using the foreach loop, but it results in the same error

```
foreach ($postResult as $array) {
    echo $array['Name'];
}
```

Here is the output for $result,

```
Aws\Result Object
 (
  [data:Aws\Result:private] => Array
  (
   [CelebrityFaces] => Array
   (
    [0] => Array
    (
     [Name] => Emily Blunt                         
    )                          
   )
  )
 )
```

I've just started using PHP a few days back, so I'm just a beginner. And also I tried searching for a specific answer but it always threw the same error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you add output of `print_r($result);`

Comment: I've added the output for $result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$result` is the object of class `Aws\Result`. According to [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.Result.html) the following should work:

```
$celebFaces = $result->get('CelebrityFaces');
foreach($celebFaces as $face) {
    echo $face['Name'];
}
```